# Reinstalling Ubuntu which option to choose in Device for Boot Loader Installation

Tags: boot, 16.04, dual-boot, 20.04, bootloader

I already have ubuntu 16.04 on my machine and am installing 20.04.
I also have GRUB BootLoader.
I have seen some videos on installing 20.04 on youtube,
almost every video says to choose "/" in device for bootloader installation.
The reason given (as I understand it) is that there would be no overriding windows bootloader problem.
Can someone please explain what issue this is referring to in detail?
Also, as I already have GRUB Bootloader, shall I keep the option in device for bootloader installation the default one, or should I change it to "/"?
Edit:
I also have windows on the same machine which I do not plan to erase.

Comment: Also, shall I install 22.04 instead of 20,04?

Comment: Yes, you should install the latest LTS version for 5 years support, of course. Ubuntu 22.04 pretty much installs the same way your old 16.04 did so no need to watch YT for that. What you should do is to backup all your personal files somewhere else and then choose the option to erase and install... so it does everything automatically for you. By far the best option if you're confused about "/" and Grub.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I also have windows on the same machine which I do not plan to remove. Therefore I am hesitant to use "erase and install", it will remove windows also, right? I have added it as clarification in the post.

Comment: Indeed, if your dual-booting you shouldn't. You can select "something else" and then select the same partitions and format (recommended because there are huge different between the releases, keeping /home isn't advisable). That is, after doing the backup, of course. Also, if you have a separated swap partition you may now simply delete it, ditto for a separated /home if applicable.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thanks! Is there any specific reason for not keeping swap and /home partitions? Is this only for 22.04 or also for 20.04?

Comment: Re: swap Ubuntu for some years has used a swapfile instead. You can keep the old partition if you want. Ditto for a separated /home if applicable but be sure to format it or at least delete all config hidden folders in order to avoid conflicts.